# HTML to PDF result in landscape

Tags: pdfsharp, xhtmlrenderer

I am using PDFSharp to generate PDF from html source.

```
PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PageSize.A4);
```

Generate to pdf works well, but I dont know how I can change page orientation to landscape?

Comment: Wrong tag: PdfGenerator is not part of PDFsharp.

Comment: Yes, but I cant use right tag htmlrenderer.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this as I require landscape mode when using `PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf`?  Also looks like HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp is no longer supported so unless someone has managed to implement landscape mode when generating Pdf's from HTML I may have to grab the source code and make the changes myself.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I had to manual create this page by MigraDoc.

Answer (score 17):

the following code could be usefull for you:

```
        var config = new PdfGenerateConfig();
        config.PageOrientation= PageOrientation.Landscape;
        config.PageSize = PageSize.A4;

        PdfDocument pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(documentHtmlContent, config);

        pdf.Save(FILE_OUT_PATH);

        Process.Start(FILE_OUT_PATH);
```